# "Segunda-feira" possui hífen?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

Qual é o correto de se utilizar ao se referir a um dia da semana, *segunda-feira* ou *segunda feira?*

E com o [acordo ortográfico de 1990 no Brasil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990#Brasil) ocorreu alguma mudança ou continua da mesma forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os dias da semana continuam sendo escritos com hífen mesmo depois do acordo ortográfico.

> A forma correta de escrita da palavra é segunda-feira, com hífen. As
>   palavras segunda feira, escritas de forma separada, sem hífen, estão
>   erradas.  Devemos utilizar o substantivo feminino segunda-feira sempre
>   que quisermos referir o segundo dia da semana, que fica entre o
>   domingo e a terça-feira.

Fonte 1: [Dúvidas de Português - Dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/segunda-feira-ou-segunda-feira/)

Fonte 2: [Nova Escola](https://novaescola.org.br/conteudo/329/pelas-novas-regras-ortograficas-como-uso-o-hifen-em-segunda-feira-super-homem-e-bem-vindo)

Comment: Seria regra geral usar hífen em nomes compostos por um substantivo e um numeral ordinal/partitivo ("segunda-feira", "matéria-prima", "obra-prima", "meia-vida" etc.)? Me parece que cada um desses casos é definido individualmente.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a [resposta do @Peixoto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4706/1798), segue trecho da [Íntegra do Acordo Ortogrático](http://download.uol.com.br/educacao/UOL_Educacao_Integra_do_Acordo_Ortografico.pdf), na página 16:

> **Base XV: Do hífen em compostos, locuções e encadeamentos vocabulares**
>
> 1º) Emprega-se o hífen nas palavras compostas por justaposição que não contêm formas de ligação e cujos elementos, de natureza nominal, adjetival, numeral ou verbal, constituem uma unidade sintagmática e semântica e mantêm acento próprio, podendo dar-se o caso de o primeiro elemento estar reduzido: *ano-luz, arcebispo-bispo, arco-íris, decreto-lei, és-sueste, médico-cirurgião, rainha-cláudia, tenente-coronel, tio-avô, turma-piloto; alcaide-mor, amorperfeito, guarda-noturno, mato-grossense, norte-americano, porto-alegrense, sul-africano; afro-asiático, afro-luso-brasileiro, azul-escuro, luso-brasileiro, primeiro-ministro, primeiro-sargento, primo-infeção, **segunda-feira**; conta-gotas, finca-pé, guarda-chuva.*

E na página 20 há ainda a orientação para escrever com a inicial minúscula:

> **Base XIX: Das minúsculas e maiúsculas**
>
> 1º) A letra minúscula inicial é usada:
>   ...
>
> b) Nos nomes dos dias, meses, estações do ano: ***segunda-feira***; outubro; primavera.

<sup>*Confesso que ainda achava que os dias da semana deveriam ser escritos com inicial maiúscula.*</sup>

---

A Íntegra do Acordo também pode ser encontrada [neste link](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990), e as  informações acima (uso do hífen e iniciais minúsculas) são encontradas nas Bases [XV](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=15-1&version=1990) e [XIX](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=19-1&version=1990).

Comment: Não consegui aceder à tua página do AO90; está disponível também no [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990).

Comment: @Jacinto Atualizei a resposta, adicionando este link. Obrigado!

Comment: Os dias da semana aprendi que eram escritos com inicial maiúscula, assim ainda os escrevo (vou parar). Notei que corretores ortográficos atuais sugerem minúscula, isto me fez suspeitar de algo no acordo ortográfico. E é !